# Generate Own Custom CSS Button with icon

Tags: plugins, tinymce, buttons

I recently changed my WordPress theme and noticed that all the buttons in previous theme are gone and are now looking like this on my new theme:

```
[button link="http://.....com" style="download" color="primary"]Download Latest Me[/button]
```

The style is the download icon while primary represents Green color.

I simply need a guide here on where and how I can create a similar plugin or tinymce as I have over 300 of these already posted :(

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is from a short code, a shortcode that does not exist anymore. Since you've changed themes and seeing this, it means that that shortcode is defined in your previous theme's functions.php

What you'll need to do is, look at your previous theme's functions file, and locate where the shortcode is defined. If you have a proper code editor, you can just search for something like [`add_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode). That action will look something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'button', 'some_function_name' );
function some_function_name() {}
```

You need to copy all of that. This **needs** to go into a [**functionality plugin**](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=functionailty%20plugin&oq=functionailty%20plugin&aqs=chrome..69i57.5898j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Never add shortcodes into your theme, rather create a plugin and add them in there. This should solve your problem

Comment: Just checking in to see what is the status of your problem, is it resolved yet. If my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting my answer. If mine did not meet your standards and you manage to resolve this issue yourself, please consider posting and accepting your own answer. Would be nice to know how you've resolved this :-). If you are still having this problem, feel free to post a comment to my answer explaining where my answer are lacking. Many thanks